# How to generate auto text font change when typing text dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I am using a UITextView and I wonder if it's possible to auto-resize the text depending to the text typing.I mean when the user taps a long text the font size of that text reduces dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a delegate method in `UITextViewDelegate` that tells you when the text has changed. You can use the `textView.text.length` property and perform some calculations on it, say, `14 - textView.text.length*3/100` if you want the text to be 14pt at start, and 11pt when it has 100 characters in it. Then you set your textfield's font right away.